# Bayesian Credibility applied to Regression

Tags: bayesian

I have a set of points $(x,y)$ with the goal of predicting $y$. I am fitting a regression model of the form $\ln(y-1) = A + B\ln(x)$.

I am reading an article that gives me the following information: "using Bayes credibility, Bayes' formula would be used: $$f(\text{Parameters}|\text{Data}) \sim f(\text{Data}|\text{Parameters}) * f(\text{Parameters})...,$$ and later on, "the regression parameters would be used for calculating this prior likelihood component, which is the credibility component of the likelihood". The article also mentions complement curves, non-weighted curves, and credibility weighted curves.

I am not familiar with how to apply credibility as described in this article. I only understand the basic fitting of the regression.
Given the following

[image: Raw Dataset]

I have fit the regression model to this as described initially (without Credibility). I would like to know how to create the points for the complement and the points for the credibility weighted portion. I think that seeing an example would help me understand the concept. On this graph I want to ultimately show all curves leading to the credibility weighted portion.

[image]

The author provided a similar graph that I would like to eventually replicate on the full dataset:

[image]

As a side note, if anyone can suggest a good reading on this topic for a novice like myself it would also be appreciated.
Thank you.

The referenced article can be found here:
http://www.variancejournal.org/issues/11-01-02/95.pdf

Comment: What expected value are you finding in your regression, $\mathbb{E}[ln(y-1)]$ or $ln(\mathbb{E}[y]-1)?$

Comment: This E[ln(y−1)]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
It's not clear from your question how the authors of the mentioned article use the credibility (which is different from the credible interval of the Bayesian estimates).

**EDIT 2:**
After reading the article, the Bayesian credibility is defined setting a Normal prior and Normal likelihood. In this case, it coincides with Buhlmann credibility ([Jewell, W. (1974). ”Credible means are exact Bayesian for exponential families.” Astin
Bulletin, 8, 1: 77–90.](https://www.casact.org/library/astin/vol8no1/77.pdf))

Still valid readings - if interested in Bayesian statistics and modelling -
Good starting points are (not in a specific order):

- "Statistical Rethinking" by Richard McElreath,
- "A Student’s Guide to Bayesian Statistics" by Ben Lambert
- "Bayesian Data Analysis" by Andrew Gelman et al.

From a practical point of view, I would suggest learning the R package `brms`. You can find a fantastic port of Statistical Rethinking to `brms` by Solomon Kurz here https://bookdown.org/ajkurz/Statistical_Rethinking_recoded/

As an example, I'm showing some code used to reproduce Figure 7 and 10 of the article:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(splines)

dat=c()
dat=rbind(dat,
          cbind(seq(12, 12*9, 12),
                c(12,28,49,65,75,85,90,93,94),
                rep(2009, 9)),
          cbind(seq(12, 12*8, 12),
                c(11,29,50,66,77,86,93,96),
                rep(2010, 8)),
          cbind(seq(12, 12*7,12),
                c(10,28,49,65,74,85,91),
                rep(2011,7)),
          cbind(seq(12,12*6,12),
                c(11,29,52,70,81,92),
                rep(2012,6)),
          cbind(seq(12,12*5,12),
                c(12,34,55,73,85),
                rep(2013,5)),
          cbind(seq(12,12*4,12),
                c(13,36,65,84),
                rep(2014,4)),
          cbind(seq(12,12*3,12),
                c(13,37,61),
                rep(2015,3)),
          cbind(seq(12,12*2,12),
                c(15,40),
                rep(2016,2)),
          cbind(12, 18, 2017)
)

cred=c()
cred=rbind(cred,
           cbind(seq(12, 12*9, 12),
                 c(2,7,14,21,25,29,32,34,35),
                 rep(2009, 9)),
           cbind(seq(12, 12*8, 12),
                 c(2,8,16,22,27,31,35,37),
                 rep(2010, 8)),
           cbind(seq(12, 12*7,12),
                 c(2,8,19,27,33,38,42),
                 rep(2011,7)),
           cbind(seq(12,12*6,12),
                 c(2,8,17,25,30,35),
                 rep(2012,6)),
           cbind(seq(12,12*5,12),
                 c(3,9,19,28,34),
                 rep(2013,5)),
           cbind(seq(12,12*4,12),
                 c(3,9,21,29),
                 rep(2014,4)),
           cbind(seq(12,12*3,12),
                 c(3,11,22),
                 rep(2015,3)),
           cbind(seq(12,12*2,12),
                 c(3,10),
                 rep(2016,2)),
           cbind(12, 3, 2017)
)

weight <- c()
for (y in c(2009:2017)) {
  tmp <- cred[cred[,3]==y, , drop=FALSE]
  if (nrow(tmp) < 2) next()
  for (j in 2:nrow(tmp)) {
    weight <- rbind(weight,
                    c(12*(j-1), tmp[j,2]/tmp[j-1,2], y))
  }
}
colnames(weight) <- c("Age", "weight", "Year")
weight <- as.data.frame(weight)

ldf <- c()
for (y in c(2009:2017)) {
  tmp <- dat[dat[,3]==y, , drop=FALSE]
  if (nrow(tmp) < 2) next()
  for (j in 2:nrow(tmp)) {
    ldf <- rbind(ldf,
                 c(12*(j-1), tmp[j,2]/tmp[j-1,2], y))
  }
}

colnames(ldf) <- c("Age", "LDF", "Year")
ldf <- as.data.frame(ldf)

dat_avg <- ldf %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarise(Y=mean(LDF))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

w_avg <- weight %>%
  group_by(Age) %>%
  summarise(W=mean(weight))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

# Model 2.3
mdl_2.3 <- lm(log(Y-1) ~ bs(Age, degree=2), data=dat_avg)

# Figure 7
plot(dat_avg$Age, dat_avg$Y, type="b")
points(dat_avg$Age, exp(predict(mdl_2.3, data.frame(Age=dat_avg$Age)))+1, col="red")
lines(dat_avg$Age, exp(predict(mdl_2.3, data.frame(Age=dat_avg$Age)))+1, col="red")
```

[image]

```r
# Figure 10
plot(w_avg$Age, w_avg$W, col="red", type="b")
points(dat_avg$Age, dat_avg$Y)
lines(dat_avg$Age, dat_avg$Y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is great info! Can this info be used like Buhlmann credibility where Z = credibility weight, Y = prediction, C = complement to Y such that Weighted Prediction = Z(Y) + (1-Z)*C. I think this was the authors intent given he talked about the unweighted, weighted, and complement curves. Forgive me if this is obvious in your answer, I'm trying to understand to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Can you please add more details about how the Bayesian credibility is related to the regression model? Your question is not clear about that.